# Is there a way to control xfce-pulseaudio-plugin (pavucontrol) with command line?

Tags: linux, audio, xfce, alsa, pulse-audio

Trying to setup media control shortcuts in Xfce (Play/Pause, Next track). I have xfce-pulseaudio-plugin which use pavucontrol. Is there a way to switch tracks via pavucontrol command line interface? Or may be there is other solution? For example I created volume shortcuts with amixer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after a short dialogue with ChatGPT. You can use the `playerctl` utility to control audio.

```
playerctl play-pause
playerctl next
```

etc.